# Expo BackgroundFetch + AsyncStorage problem

Tags: android, node.js, typescript, react-native, expo-go

My app uses Expo BackgroundFetch ([Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/background-fetch/)) to run tasks while it is in the background (minimized). One of the tasks is to fetch the location of the device and send to an API to create a history of locations, that later will be used to create a route in a map. If the user don't have internet connection, my app must save the location of the device internally, and when the connection is stabilished, the cicle continues, taking the stored locations and sending it to the API. This cicle occurs every few minutes. The problem is, i can't make Async Storage works together with Expo BackgroundFetch. Any suggestions of what can i do to make it work, or any suggestions of other tools that can replace Async Storage?

I tryed Async Storage ([Docs](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage/), in this version. I'm using React Native, Typescript, Expo Go and NodeJs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.